# How to add texture to top of acorn cap?

Tags: texturing

I'm attempting to add the leaf-like texture to an acorn cap similar to the attached photo. I'm planning to 3D print the final product so I need to actually alter the mesh, not just paint on an image texture.

I've tried creating a single acorn cap "leaf" and added a Shrinkwrap modifier to the main body of the acorn, but the results were terrible. It flattened my "leaf" and made it essentially 2D.

I'm not sure if making a separate object and trying to conform it to body of the acorn is the right way to go. Or would it be better to try and deform/sculpt the cap to create the texture?

Could anybody recommend a tool that might get me started in the right direction? I'm new to Blender. [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, for example prepare your basic shape, make a copy, subdivide, in *Sculpt* mode enable a radial symmetry on Z:

[image]

Then sculpt as much as necessary until you're satisfied:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the radial symmetry option. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Update: After I figured out I needed to CTRL+A my location and rotation the radial symmetry option worked beautifully. You're the best!  Also, just out of curiosity, why did you suggest I make a copy before subdividing and sculpting? Was that just to make a backup just in case?

Comment: because if you mess up the sculpting it's better to keep the original shape in order to redo it